# issues with looping, calling functions to loop

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I have to write a program that performs Egyptian type of multiplication. I have the math correct(for the most part) But I've searched and searched and searched and can't really pin point down a correct loop.

I need the program to loop the calculation part, ending with it asking if you want to loop it again to put in different numbers. I also need a negative section, to calculate the outcome if using negative numbers, which I am completely drawing a blank to do.

What I've got so far:

```
import math

def egyptian(positive):
    a,b = raw_input('Please input the two numbers separated by a space').split()
a = int(a)
b = int(b)
answer = 0
while b != 0:
    if (a%2 != 0):
        print "B was odd, we add A to make the product: ", (a)
        answer = answer+a
        a = a*2
        b = b//2
    if (b%2 == 0):
        a = A*2
        b = b//2
print "The product of the two numbers is", (answer)


choice = ""
if choice != "y" or "Y":
    choice = raw_input("Do you want to continue?(y/n)")
if choice == "Y" or "y":
    goto NO idea what to put here to get it to loop.        
if choice != "Y" or "y":
    print "Quitting"
```

I understand the choice part at the bottom is probably way off for what I want it to do.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score -1):

I don't see where you are calling your egyptian function? But what you can do is you can put all of the code inside of the egyptian function, and then you can have the function call itself to make it loop again.

Also the line `choice = ""` should be `choice = raw_input("Do you want to continue?(y/n)")`. You need to ask for the input first, and then once you have their input you add the correct logic to determine if they would like to loop again.

There is another way you could solve this issue, but it's not as good of a solution because it's always better to break your code down into smaller function, but you could also have a loop inside of a loop. The outer loop would decide if you should loop again, the inner loop does the egyptian multiplication code.